# Need To Import HTML values From Google Sheets to Google WebApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on the Search crud via Google webapp, I want to display the HTML design on front end via fetching it from Google sheets cells. Showing some examples in the screen shot

Google Sheet cell contains with HTML codes
[image]

The front end doesn't display the HTML design from the Google sheets but displaying the data with HTML code.
[image]

Here is my Script Code

main.html

```
</head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
   
     <div id="app"></div>   

  <!-- Content here -->
</div>

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  <script>
  
  var data;
  
  function loadView(options){
var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "app" : options.id;
var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function(){} : options.callback;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html){
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;
typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params);
})[options.func]();
}

function setDataForSearch(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){
data = dataReturned.slice();
}).getDataForSearch();
}

function search(){

var searchinput = document.getElementById("searchinput").value.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
var searchWords = searchinput.split(/\s+/);
var searchColumns = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

// and or

var resultsArray = data.filter(function(r){


return searchWords.every(function(word){
return searchColumns.some(function(colIndex){
return r[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !== -1
});

});

});
var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
var template = templateBox.content;

searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";

resultsArray.forEach(function(r){

var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
var l1Column = tr.querySelector(".L1");
var l2Column = tr.querySelector(".L2");
var l3Column = tr.querySelector(".L3");
var l4Column = tr.querySelector(".L4");
var l5Column = tr.querySelector(".L5");
var l6Column = tr.querySelector(".L6");
var l7Column = tr.querySelector(".L7");
var l8Column = tr.querySelector(".L8");

l1Column.textContent = r[0];
l2Column.textContent = r[1];
l3Column.textContent = r[2];
l4Column.textContent = r[3];
l5Column.textContent = r[4];
l6Column.textContent = r[5];
l7Column.textContent = r[6];
l8Column.textContent = r[7];

searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);

});
}

function loadSearchView(){
loadView({func:"loadSearchView", callback: setDataForSearch});
}


window.addEventListener("load", loadSearchView);


function inputEventHandler(e){
if (e.target.matches("#searchinput")){
  search();
}
}
document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("input",inputEventHandler);
    
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

search.html

```
<div class="form-group">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchinput" placeholder="search...">
 </div>

 

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">Id</th>
      <th scope="col">First Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone Number</th>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
      <th scope="col">City</th>
      <th scope="col">Street</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="searchResults">
  
  </tbody>
</table>


<template id="rowTemplate">
 <tr>
      
      <td class="L1"></td>
      <td class="L2"></td>
      <td class="L3"></td>
      <td class="L4"></td>
      <td class="L5"></td>
      <td class="L6"></td>
      <td class="L7"></td>
      <td class="L8"></td>

  </tr>
</template>
```

serversidefunc.gs

```
function getDataForSearch(){
    
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("customer");
  
  return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(),8).getValues();

}
```

loadpartials.gs

```
function loadPartialHTML_(partial) {
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(partial);
  return htmlServ.evaluate().getContent();
  
}

function loadSearchView(){
 
   return loadPartialHTML_("search");
}
```

I Hope my above post is clear.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following modification for the function of `search()` in Javascript side?

#### From:

```
l1Column.textContent = r[0];
l2Column.textContent = r[1];
l3Column.textContent = r[2];
l4Column.textContent = r[3];
l5Column.textContent = r[4];
l6Column.textContent = r[5];
l7Column.textContent = r[6];
l8Column.textContent = r[7];
```

#### To:

```
l1Column.innerHTML = r[0];
l2Column.innerHTML = r[1];
l3Column.innerHTML = r[2];
l4Column.innerHTML = r[3];
l5Column.innerHTML = r[4];
l6Column.innerHTML = r[5];
l7Column.innerHTML = r[6];
l8Column.innerHTML = r[7];
```

#### Reference:

- [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Im having a small issue along with it, when i click on the link for India, it's opening up with this url https://n-cyghwq3ery4b5c7vgjmecxfr24dpholnua3hg2q-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/www.google.com where unable to open it. any reason?

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil About your new question, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in this case, I would like to recommend to post it as new question. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon because of my poor skill. I would like to study more.

Comment: sure, Ill do that. :) Thank you for the support. really appreciate it.

Comment: @Muhammed Aadhil Thank you for replying. I really apologize I cannot resolve your new questions soon.